# How can i fix my code to put each paragraph in a new line, as I am trying to add paragraph before the given paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add paragraphs before the paragraphs in HTML, but the somehow the code is not printing them in a newline. I need to print them as:

Para-1

Para-2

Para-3

Para-4

Instead it is printing  in a line as: Para-1Para-2Para-3Para-4

```js
  const paraList = [
        {
            par: "Para-1",
        },
        {
            par: "Para-2",
        },
        {
            par: "Para-3",                                                                                                                      
        },
        {
            par: "Para-4",
        },
    ];
    
    let para = document.createElement("p");
    for (var i = 0; i < paraList.length; ++i) {
        let node = document.createTextNode(paraList[i].par);
        para.appendChild(node);

        let element = document.getElementById("div1");
        let child = document.getElementById("p1");
        element.insertBefore(para,child);
    }
```

```html
 <div id="div1">
     <p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
     <p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new paragraph for each element of the list, you should create a new element each time, so put the declaration inside the loop like this:

```js
const paraList = [
    {
        par: "Para-1",
    },
    {
        par: "Para-2",
    },
    {
        par: "Para-3",                                                                                                                      
    },
    {
        par: "Para-4",
    },
];
    
for (var i = 0; i < paraList.length; ++i) {
    let para = document.createElement("p");
    let node = document.createTextNode(paraList[i].par);
    para.appendChild(node);

    let element = document.getElementById("div1");
    let child = document.getElementById("p1");
    element.insertBefore(para,child);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
     <p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
     <p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>
```